# Limit of $\frac{\frac{\sin x}{x^2} - \sin (\sin x)}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the limit

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin x}{x^2} - \sin (\sin x)}{x^2} ?$$

I think this limit equal to $K$, since $K \neq 0$, end $K \neq\infty$. Your opinion?

Comment: Soo sorry!, my function is:

Comment: I don't think that my opinion or anybody's opinion to be relevant.

Comment: What's your $K$?

Comment: Soo sorry!, my function is: [  Sinx/x² - Sin(Sinx) ]/x²

Comment: Is it okay now?

Comment: Still you need to let us know what is $K$....

Comment: Looks like the first year university exercise on Maclaurin's expansion, but it is something wrong here, must be a typo.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this limit you can use the approximation $\sin x \approx x$ when $x \approx 0$.

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin x}{x^2} - \sin (\sin x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{x}{x^2} - x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x^3}-x\right)$$
which is $+\infty$ from the right and $-\infty$ from the left

Answer (score 1):

The limit of the numerator is $+\infty$ when $x\to0^+$ and $-\infty$ from the left. Since the denominator tends to $0$ and it is non-negative,

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\frac{\sin x}{x^2} - \sin (\sin x)}{x^2}=\infty$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\frac{\sin x}{x^2} - \sin (\sin x)}{x^2}=-\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin x}{x^2} - \sin (\sin x)}{x^2}=$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)-x^2\sin(\sin(x))}{x^4}$$

So we find that a two-sided limit not exist!

---

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{\sin(x)-x^2\sin(\sin(x))}{x^4}=$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sin(x)-x^2\sin(\sin(x))\right)}{\frac{d}{dx}x^4}=$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{1}{4x^3}\left(\cos(x)-x^2\cos(x)\cos(\sin(x))-2x\sin(\sin(x))\right)=$$

$$\frac{1}{4}\left(\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\left(\lim_{x\to 0^-}\left(\cos(x)-x^2\cos(x)\cos(\sin(x))-2x\sin(\sin(x))\right)\right)=$$

(Since $\cos(x)-x^2\cos(x)\cos(\sin(x))$ is a continuous function of $x$)

$$\frac{1}{4}\left(\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\left(\lim_{x\to 0^-}\left(\cos(0)-0^2\cos(0)\cos(\sin(0))-2\times 0\sin(\sin(0))\right)\right)=$$

$$\frac{1}{4}\left(\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\left(1\right)=\frac{1\times \lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{1}{x^3}}{4}=\frac{1\times -\infty}{4}=-\infty$$

---

The $\lim_{x\to 0^+}$ is the opposite of the negative one so:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sin(x)-x^2\sin(\sin(x))}{x^4}=\infty$$

---